# IE9 CSS center positioning

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9, position, center

Please refer to the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AYv32/6/) for example.

I am trying to render a popup message which should appear in the centre of the screen.

Problem: IE9 renders it on the left hand side, IE8 renders correct in the centre, Chrome & Firefox are happy displaying in the centre as well.

CSS code of the element (.cPUParent):

```
.cPUParent {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  left: 5px;
  right: 0;
  width: auto;
  max-width: 187px;
  height: auto;
  padding: 5px 10px 0 15px;
  border: 2px solid #571C54;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background-color: rgb(109,49,107);
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";    /* opacity in IE 8 */
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);  /* opacity in IE 5-7 */
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

Comment: unrelated but you should probably remove the div before you add it again, button can be spanned for many many divs

Comment: I actually want that effect, if the user desires, they may go ahead and click to their heart's content.

Answer (score 1):

Changing 'max-width' to 'width' in the .cPUParent class makes it work in IE9:

http://jsfiddle.net/rLwvP/

```
.cPUParent {
  width: 187px;
}
```

Comment: I cannot predefine the width.

Answer (score 1):

What you have to consider is the height and the width of the object.
If you can set a fixed width, then its quite easy.
Here is the solution which works on ie8 and 9.

```
    .cPUParent {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        right: auto;
        bottom: auto;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        margin-left: -64.5px;
        margin-top: -54.5px;

        padding: 5px 10px 0 15px;
        border: 2px solid #571C54;
        border-radius: 5px;
        background-color: #6D316B;
        -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
        filter: alpha(opacity=0);
        opacity: 0;
        z-index: 999;
    }
```

To explain:
If you can set the height and width (100px in this example) then you need to push it 50% in from the left of the screen border and from the top 50%.

```
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
```

When you do this, it sets the box's top left corner on that 50%/50% point so you then need to pull it up and left a little (half the height and width of the box). (consider the box model when working this out. The padding and border all add to the width and height of the object)

```
        margin-left: -64.5px;
        margin-top: -54.5px;
```

The bottom and right values should be reset to auto just incase there are other cascading styles being applied to it

```
        right: auto;
        bottom: auto;
```

The rest of the code is your original styles:

```
        padding: 5px 10px 0 15px;
        border: 2px solid #571C54;
        border-radius: 5px;
        background-color: #6D316B;
        -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
        filter: alpha(opacity=0);
        opacity: 0;
        z-index: 999;
```

Dont forget that you wont see anything at the moment because you have opacity set to 0 (ZERO).

```
        -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
        filter: alpha(opacity=0);
        opacity: 0;
```

And that should do it.

Comment: Also, don't forget that you should bump up the z-index so that it floats on top of everything on the page. Especially as this is a popup message that you're after. As you can see i set it to 999 which will make sure that nothing sits on top of it most of the time

Comment: thanks for the effect Arathol, however, I cannot set the width as the notifications may vary in size.

Comment: If you then want it to be truly centralized all the time, you would have to programmatically (is that a word - it should be!) pick up the width and height of the box using javascript and then you will be able to change the css of the negative left and top margin using jscript after that. Unfortunately, i am still learning javascript so wouldnt be able to help you out there.

Comment: Thanks Arathol, but I wonder why? FF, Chrome render it fine, IE8 (!) renders it fine, its IE9 that being a pain.

Comment: The problem is you shouldn't have a left and right value. Some browsers render that oddly. on some browsers it will pull the left border to your "left: px" value and also pull the right border to your "right: px" value, stretching the box. You set a max-width which stops it though. Take my code and instead of putting "width:100px" keep it at "width: 100%", and add your "max-width: 187px;" in there and make your left margin -108px (negative 108 px). Then at least your box will be centered when the content takes up the full width (187px) and will be off to the left a bit when it doesn't.